# I have a simple Odd or Even test in Ruby but it's not working

Tags: ruby

I'm sort of a beginner but I cannot figure out why I this code isn't working in ruby. It only returns "That's not even" even if the number is completely divisible by 2.

```
def numbertest()
print "Input your number here."
number1=gets.chomp
print "Okay, let's see if #{number1} 's odd or even."
    if number1.even? 
        print "That's even."
    else
        print "That's not even."
    end 
end

numbertest()
```

Comment: Your code can't work, you are calling a number method (`even?`) on a string (`number1`)

Comment: Something is wrong here, that is not valid ruby code. It shouldn't even run, never mind not work. `even?` is not a valid method for String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets.chomp` returns a string. Call `to_i` on `number1` so it becomes an integer and responds to `even?`:

```
def numbertest()
print "Input your number here."
number1=gets.chomp.to_i
print "Okay, let's see if #{number1} 's odd or even."
    if number1.even? 
        print "That's even."
    else
        print "That's not even."
    end 
end
```

Comment: That worked! I called to_i. Does gets.chomp always return a string even if the input is a number? I tried to do it with the modulus operator too and that wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually, it is `gets` that returns a string. `chomp` removes the last character of a string. The other code wouldn't have worker either because the problem isn't on your logic, but on the `number1` variable. Also, could you accept the answer?

Comment: -1 for having a redundant `chomp`, and for asking the OP to accept the answer, which goes against how this site works.

Comment: @sawa oh sorry, thought that it would make it easier for future searches.

Answer (score 2):

`number1` is a string. It never satisfies `even?`. But what is mysterious is that it should return an undefined method error, but you do not seem to have that.

Comment: I guess he's referring to some modified version of the code which uses a method valid for strings, like f.e. `number1 % 2`: in such case the code works but returns always "That's even."